# prevent only one line going to the next column

Tags: multicol, columnbreak

I have two files

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{multicol} 

\newcommand{\block}[1]{
    \input{"#1.tex"}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}%
    \block{Klopp}   
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

**Klopp.tex**

```
Zur Saison 2015/16 verließ die Vereinslegende Steven Gerrard nach insgesamt 26 Jahren den Verein in Richtung Los Angeles Galaxy. Nach dem 8. Spieltag wurde Brendan Rodgers nach einem 1:1-Unentschieden im Merseyside Derby gegen den FC Everton entlassen. Zu diesem Zeitpunkt stand das Team mit 12 Punkten auf dem 10. Tabellenplatz. Als sein Nachfolger wurde Jürgen Klopp verpflichtet, der nach sieben Jahren Tätigkeit bei Borussia Dortmund seit Saisonbeginn pausiert hatte. In Klopps Premierensaison gelang ihm der Einzug in das Finale der Europa League, das im St. Jakob-Park mit 1:3 gegen den FC Sevilla verloren ging. In der Liga verpasste man mit zwei Punkten Rückstand nur knapp die Qualifikation zur Europa League 2016/2017. Im FA Cup wurde das Achtelfinale nach einer 1:2-Niederlage gegen West Ham United verpasst.\\
    \newline
    %
    Die Saison 2016/17 begann mit einem 4:3-Auswärtssieg bei Arsenal London. Auch der FC Chelsea konnte am 5. Spieltag in London geschlagen werden. Zuvor blieb man bereits beim amtierenden Meister Leicester City als auch bei den Spurs ohne Niederlage. Nach dem 11. Spieltag stand der FC Liverpool erstmals seit Mai 2014 wieder an der Tabellenspitze der Liga. Die Saison endete mit dem vierten Tabellenplatz und der damit verbundenen Qualifikation für die Playoffs der UEFA Champions League 2017/18.\\
    \newline
    %
    In der Saison 2017/18 erreichte der Klub zum ersten Mal seit elf Jahren das Finale der UEFA Champions League, welches mit 1:3 gegen Real Madrid verloren ging.
```

If I run the main.tex file it looks like this:
[image]

Can I prevent only one line going to the next column (see red marking)? Can this problem be solved with one command? I want to avoid something like *gegen~West~Ham~United~verpasst*.

Thank you!

Comment: the markup `\\\newline` apart from making underful boxes makes this harder than it should be as the whole text is a single paragraph, and the white space is not a vertical space as would occur between paragraphs (and be dropped at a column or page break) it is a blank line of text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would also be happy with a solution with vertical space in between. No need to solve the case with \\\newline.